# Subsetting dataframe by two columns from other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datasets containing names. What is the easist pythonish way to subset df2 so it contains onlys rows df1 is containing (first, last name). Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

names1 = {
    'index' : [1, 2, 3], 
    'col1'  : ['John', 'Jerry', 'John'],
    'col2'  : ['Doe', 'Peters', 'Smith']
}




names2 = {
    'index' : [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'col1'  : ['John', 'Bob','Jerry', 'John'],
    'col2'  : ['Smith', 'Lacko', 'Peters', 'Nowak'],
    'col3'  : [12, 13, 14, 15]
}


df1 = pd.DataFrame(names1).set_index(["index"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(names2).set_index(["index"])

print(df1,'\n')
print(df2)

        col1    col2
index               
1       John     Doe
2      Jerry  Peters
3       John   Smith 

        col1    col2  col3
index                     
1       John   Smith    12
2        Bob   Lacko    13
3      Jerry  Peters    14
4       John   Nowak    15
```

desired output:

```
       col1   col2   col3
index                     
1      John   Smith    12
3      Jerry  Peters   14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) before [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df2.reset_index().merge(df1).set_index('index')
print (df)
        col1    col2  col3
index                     
1       John   Smith    12
3      Jerry  Peters    14
```

because only `merge` lost original index values:

```
print (df2.merge(df1))
    col1    col2  col3
0   John   Smith    12
1  Jerry  Peters    14
```